# How is a javelin throw measured if the javelin does not stick into the ground?

Tags: rules, track-and-field

If a javelin "slips" on landing and does not stick cleanly into the field, how is the throw measured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered by the [IAAF Competition Rules](http://www.iaaf.org/about-iaaf/documents/rules-regulations). Quoting from the 2014–2015 edition, Rule 187.20:

> The measurement of each throw shall be made [...] from where the head of the javelin first struck the ground to the inside edge of the arc, along a line to the centre of the circle of which the arc is part.